# Java Auto completion does not display my method created in an interface

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, content-assist

I am trying to call a method from a object with type being an `interface`.

```
    private Car Ferrari;
    Ferrari.startEngine();
```

`Car` is the `interface` class with a method called `startEngine()`.

I also have a class that implements `Car`, lets call it `CarImplementation`. So when I call `Ferrari.startEngine()`, I'm assuming that the `startEngine()` in CarImplementation will be called.

However, in Eclipse, I get a red line under `startEngine()`. And I get an error message saying

> The method startEngine() is undefined for the type Car

How is it undefined when I have `startEngine()` in both my interface and the class that implements the interface ?

I also noticed that after I type the dot following Ferrari, my `startEngine()` method is **not** showing up on Eclipse's content assist.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you saved your Car.java file? :-)

Answer (score 2):

`Ferrari` is not a `Car`, it's `null` until you allocate it to an actual object.

```
Car ferrari = new CarImplementation();
ferrari.startEngine(); // works
```

(Also, I renamed your object as `ferrari` with no cap, as per Sun Java standards)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create an instance of `CarImplementation` to use it's implementation- interfaces don't have implementations on methods they define.

So if it's a non-static method, you want to try this:

```
Private Car ferrari = new CarImplementation();
ferrari.startEngine();
```